# Quiero agregar un programa a mi proyecto para ejecutarlo con el System.Diagnostics.Process.Start();

Tags: c#

Buenas, esperando su gentil ayuda, el problema es el siguiente, estoy desarrollando un aplicación de windows form en C# , tengo un formulario, para ejecutar una aplicación externa uso el System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("direccion del archivo");

En mi formulario, tengo un botón que al hacer click debe abrirme el instalador de otra aplicación, el inconveniente, es nose como hacer para que ejecute un programa que este dentro del proyecto.

Lo quiero dar a entender es como abrir aplicacion.exe desde miprograma.exe con un botón,y que ambos archivos se encuentren en la misma unidad, como por ejemplo un cd.

Comment: Es portable la aplicación externa?

Comment: En determinado caso que sí, se pudiera, y si fuese no  ??

Comment: Pues pregunto si es portable, ya que si ejecutas el programa que estas creando en otro maquina que no tengo instalado el programa externo, lanzara una excepcion. Entonces si es portable lo puedes copiar en el directorio de tu app, bin/debug entonces solo lo mandas a llamar simplemente con System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("aplicacionPortable");

Comment: Gracias, ahora todo funciona !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas Sergio,

Si la aplicación que quieres ejecutar está en el mismo directorio del programa que estás ejecutando, sólo con poner el nombre del programa que quieres ejecutar en el `Process.Start()` ya te valdría:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("nombre aplicación");
```

El caso es que cuando proporcionas un nombre sólo donde debe ir una dirección (path) te pone el path donde estás ejecutando la aplicación automáticamente.

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia, dejo un ejemplo de como abrir un ejecutable desde otra aplicación.

```
    private void btnWeb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ruta = "\\Program Files\\Iris Browser\\IrisBrowser.exe";
        //ruta: Direccion donde se encuetra la aplicacion.
        //"": Parametro en caso de que tu aplicacion este esperando un valor
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(ruta, "");
        try
        {
            Process.Start(info);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se encontro el archivo");
        }
    }
```

Espero y les sea de utilidad. Saludos.

Comment: Me ayudó mucho !! :)